# How to save and display and image in react-native?

Tags: image, react-native, store

I have a question in react-native. Im using a module called **"react-native-image-picker"** to pick an image and display it on my app.

Now what i want is to store it somewhere (database, or local storage) and when i open again the app, the image that i choosed should be there. But i dont know what is the best option to do it.

I've already tryied to read some stuff like react-native-fs and fetch-blob but it doesnt help me, i guess.

What is the best option to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Save the resulting value to your local storage and retrieve the data that you store on storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, renders view according to condition. For example if image is available then simply display the image else display TouchableOpacity which will help use to select pictures :

```js
import React, { Component } from React;
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isImageAvailable: false,
            profilePic: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getImage();
    }

    getImage = async () => {
        const profilePic = await AsyncStorage.getItem("profilePic");
        if (profilePic) {
            this.setState({
                isImageAvailable: true,
                profilePic: JSON.parse(profilePic)
            });
        }
    }

    selectProfilePic = () => {
        const options = {
            title: 'Select Avatar',
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images',
            },
        };

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            } else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            } else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            } else {
                const source = { uri: response.uri };

                // You can also display the image using data:
                // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
                AsyncStorage.setItem("profilePic", JSON.stringify(source));
                this.setState({
                    profilePic: source,
                    isImageAvailable: true
                });
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {
                    this.state.isImageAvailable && (
                        <Image source={this.state.profilePic} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />

                    )
                }

                {
                    !this.state.isImageAvailable && (
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectProfilePic}>
                            <Text>Choose Profile Pic</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey , why you use `await` with AsyncStorage?

Comment: Because it is asynchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [realmdb](https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native/) as an aternative to Asyncstorage.