# How to Captured And then save those images in react native app it self

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. I have created An app. and In this app I am able to captured image from camera and gallery also but the problem is now . I want that captured Image To store in Array And want to show that image On specific screen. I want 3-5 images to store and show on that screen

here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add({ navigation }) {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [imageArray,setImageArray] = useState([])

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    setImageArray([imageArray..] + result)
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    //   allowsEditing: true,
    //   aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageUri(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

<View style={styles.header}>
        <Ionicons style={{paddingLeft:20}} name="arrow-back" size={40} 
        color="black"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("OtherInfo")} />
        <Text style={{fontSize:20, paddingLeft: 70, paddingTop: 10}}>Get Image</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
          style={styles.fixedRatio}
          type={type}
          ratio={'1:1'}
        />
      </View>

      <Button title={'Take Picture'} onPress={takePicture} />
      <Button title={'Gallery'} onPress={pickImage} />
      {imageUri && <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  header:{
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save and display and image in react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825367/how-to-save-and-display-and-image-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in our previous chat, here is the solution:

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/quiet-chocolates)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Image, FlatList, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add() {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState([]);

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
      setImageArray([...imageArray, data.uri]);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageArray([...imageArray, result.uri]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
        style={styles.fixedRatio}
        type={type}
      />

      {imageArray.length > 0 && (
        <View style={{ height: 110 }}>
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={imageArray}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: item }}
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 10, margin: 5 }}
              />
            )}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      <Button title={'Take Picture'} onPress={takePicture} />
      <Button title={'Gallery'} onPress={pickImage} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks bro . if possible look at this = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022931/how-to-choose-file-from-button-next-to-input-filed-in-the-form-in-react-native