# How to Choose File From Button next to input filed in the form in react native. (See image for better understanding)

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. and I have created A form. Now in that form I want A choose file button next to the input filed. And when user click on that Choose file button. Either camera will open or gallery will open(as per user choice) and then When user click on choose file button A small image or just image name comes below the choose file button

here is my image for better understanding
[image]

here is my code

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import {Picker, Text, StyleSheet, View,
   TextInput, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView, Alert, alert, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions,} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, navigation} from "react-navigation";
import { Card, Badge, Block, } from "../components";
import { theme, mocks } from "../constants";
import DigSign from "./DigSign"
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");


class PickerDemo extends Component{
    

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
    };
  }
  

  validateInputs = () => {
  //  if (!this.state.accountNo.trim()) 
  if (!/[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}/.test(this.state.PAN))
  {
    this.setState({ PANError: 'Please enter valid PAN Number' })
    return;
  }
  if (!/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/.test(this.state.GST)) 
  {
    this.setState({ GSTError: 'Please enter valid GST Number' })
    return;
  }
  if (!/^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$/.test(this.state.Aadhar)) 
  {
    this.setState({ AadharError: 'Please enter valid Aadhar Number' })
    return;
  }
    else {
      Alert.alert("All fields validated")
      return;
    }
  }

  handlePAN = (text) => {
    this.setState({ PANError: '' })
    this.setState({ PAN: text })
  }
  handleGST = (text) => {
    this.setState({ GSTError: '' })
    this.setState({ GST: text })
  }
  handleAadhar = (text) => {
    this.setState({ AadharError: '' })
    this.setState({ Aadhar: text })
  }

render(){
  const offset = (Platform.OS === 'android') ? -200 : 0;
  const { navigation } = this.props;


  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>

      <View style={styles.header}>
       <Ionicons style={{paddingLeft:20}} name="arrow-back" size={40} 
      color="black"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")} />
      <Text style={{fontSize:20, paddingLeft: 70, paddingTop: 10}}>KYC Details</Text>
      </View>

    <KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={offset} style={styles.form} behavior='padding'>

      

      <Text style={styles.formLabel}> OTHER INFORMATION Form </Text>
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1,}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>   

      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>    
      <TextInput maxLength={30} placeholder="PAN Card Number *" style={styles.inputStyle}
       onChangeText={this.handlePAN} />
       <View style={{justifyContent:"center"}}>
        <Button title={'Choose File'}/>
        </View>
        </View>
        <Text>{this.state.PANError}</Text>

        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
        <TextInput maxLength={30}  placeholder="GSTIN Number*" style={styles.inputStyle}
         onChangeText={this.handleGST} />
        <View style={{justifyContent:"center"}}>
        <Button title={'Choose File'}/>
        </View>
        </View>
        <Text>{this.state.GSTError}</Text>

        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
        <TextInput maxLength={30} placeholder="Aadhar Card Number*" style={styles.inputStyle}
         onChangeText={this.handleAadhar} />
        <View style={{justifyContent:"center"}}>
        <Button title={'Choose File'}/>
        </View>
        </View>
        <Text>{this.state.AadharError}</Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DigSign")}
       >
         <Card center middle shadow style={styles.category}>
           <Text medium height={1} size={1}>
             Digital Signature
           </Text>
         </Card>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       
       <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ImgpickWithCam")}
       >
         <Card center middle shadow style={styles.category}>
           <Text medium height={1} size={1}>
             Pick An Image From Camera
           </Text>
         </Card>
       </TouchableOpacity>
          
        </ScrollView>
          
        
        <View style={{ height: 30 }} />
        <Button style={styles.inputStyleB}
          title="Submit"
          color="#808080"
          onPress={() => this.validateInputs()}
        />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>


  );
};
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    form: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(247, 146, 57)",
        alignItems: 'center',
        paddingTop: 50,
      },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(247, 146, 57)",
    alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 15
  },

  formLabel: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'rgb(10, 10, 10)',
  },
  inputStyle: {
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 220,
    height: 40,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 252, 252)',
  },
  formText: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
 
  category: {
    marginTop: 20,
    
        // this should be dynamic based on screen width
    minWidth: (width - theme.sizes.padding * -10 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
    maxWidth: (width - theme.sizes.padding * -10 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
    maxHeight: (height - theme.sizes.padding * -50 - theme.sizes.base) / 2,
  },
  header:{
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
});

export default PickerDemo;
```

Comment: It is very straight forward. What problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: thanks for helping me from 2 days. Suppose I paste your code in this code but when I click on choose file then takepicture function will call. but after clicking the picture i want the camera window will close automatically. and small image or image name should shown below the choose file button

Comment: or how could I write my above code into the code which you have given me. because In above code I have created class component and in your code you have created a functional component

Comment: added the modified example based on prev answers, do check out. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution based on the previous examples that I have given you.

You just had to implement the conditional rendering to it.

Just a couple of lines of code what was needed :)

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/bold-chips)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Button,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add() {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState([]);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState([]);

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('camera permission:', cameraPermission.status);

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log('permission:', imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
      setImageArray([...imageArray, data.uri]);
      setShowCamera(false);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageArray([...imageArray, result.uri]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {showCamera && (
        <Camera ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)} style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type} />
      )}
      {showCamera && <Button title={'Click'} onPress={takePicture} />}
      {!showCamera && (
        <>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <TextInput placeholder={'Enter PAN Number'} />
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Button
                title={'Camera'}
                onPress={() => {
                  setShowCamera(true);
                }}
              />
              <Button title={'Gallery'} onPress={pickImage} />
            </View>
          </View>
          {imageArray.length > 0 && (
            <View style={{ height: 110 }}>
              <FlatList
                horizontal
                data={imageArray}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: item }}
                    style={{
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      borderRadius: 10,
                      margin: 5,
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 30,
    flex: 1,
  },

  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks bro but when I going to capture image camera window not opening. for gallery its works fine but camera window will not opening

Comment: I have not checked it on mobile, might be small bug, but the method is exactly the same. Use conditional rendering as shown.

Comment: Check now. It's working on mobile too. Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: yooo thanks bro you are legend thanks for helping me from last two days. i think you know marathi = thank you bhava khup khup dhanywad

Comment: But bro now how could i do form validation in this code because i create form validation according to the class component but in this there is functional component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228195/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-sohil-shaikh).